Two sum problem gives address sanitizer error for specific input of [0,4,3,0] with target 0
struct hashmap {
    int key;
    int val;
};

int hash_find(int num, int size, struct hashmap* hash) {
    int k, i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        k = (num + i) % size;
        if(hash[k].key == num) return hash[k].val;
    }
    return -1;
}

void hash_add(int num, int size, int index, struct hashmap* hash) {
    int k, i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        k = (num + i) % size;
        if(hash[k].key == -9999 && hash[k].val == -9999) {
            hash[k].key = num;
            hash[k].val = index;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {       
    int* res = calloc((*returnSize = 2), sizeof(int));
    struct hashmap* hash = calloc(numsSize, sizeof(struct hashmap));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        hash[i].key = -9999;
        hash[i].val = -9999;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        int k = target - nums[i];
        int result = hash_find(k, numsSize, hash);

        if(result >= 0) {
            res[0] = result;
            res[1] = i;
            break;
        } else {
            hash_add(nums[i], numsSize, i, hash);
        }
    }

    free(hash); // Free allocated memory for hash

    return res;
}

it gives address sanitizer error and highlights this line if(hash[k].key == num) return hash[k].val; when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
** i have created hash table with linear probing**
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.
it gives address sanitizer error when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0.


Do NOT tag both "C" and "C++", calloc in C++ is not a thing so you're looking for a "C" answer. (In C++ we would use std::map or std::unordered_map and not implement a map from scratch) . I removed the C++ tag

You probably have out of bounds access. Just use normal C++ std::map, or other appropriate container.

Do you have the input that give you the error? Then create a [mre], with the input hard-coded into the main function, and use a debugger or other debugging techniques to find out what the problem is.

it works on dev c++ and turbo c++. gives error only when i submit on leetcode. test case on leetcode is also passed

Just because something builds and seem to work, doesn't mean that it's free of bugs. Going out of bounds of an array or allocated memory leads to undefined behavior, which might seem to work sometimes, or crash other times. The error you're getting is because Leetcode add special options when building to catch such errors when running the program.

"when run on leetcode with testcase [0,4,3,0] with target 0" -- This information is far less useful than telling us what are the values of k, hash[k].key, num and hash[k].val (a.k.a. the expressions in the identified line).

Repeating yourself at the end of a question accomplishes two things. 1) It perverts the system's attempt to get you to improve the question by making the question worse. 2) It attracts downvotes. Neither of these are particularly desirable... Try more text and less code. Reduce the code to a [mre] and explain why each line of that code is indisputably correct.

What does % do when you feed it a negative operand?? (Have now reproduced the problem)

@AviBerger, yup % of -ve number created problem. adding abs() worked. thanks

Perhaps you should see why you get a negative number? Is it supposed to be negative? If not, then you should fix that instead of working around it.

@Someprogrammerdude it was not supposed to be negative. it tried to access array with negative index.

k = (num + i) % size; can produce a negative k that fails using it later as an array index.
This is in multiple functions.
int % is not modulo, but remainder.
Instead use an unsigned type for i and size to achieve a Euclidean modulo.  I suggest size_t.
int hash_find(int num, size_t size, struct hashmap* hash) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    size_t k = ((unsigned) num + i) % size;
    ...

If wanting to stay with int types, then use:
k = (num + i) % size;
if (k < 0) k += size;
// or
k = (int) ((unsigned) (num + i) % (unsigned) size);

